# What is a good way to go about translating Monero software to other languages?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, user-guide, language

Say I wanted to translate the Monero GUI to my language is there a good process for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Monero GUI is written with the Qt application framework that includes tools for the translation.

As one can expect, translation files are located in the [translation](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/tree/master/translations) folder.

You have to create a file for your language by copying monero-core.ts. You then fill it with the translated strings. You can do it with a text editor (replacing `with`Your translation` or with the [Qt Linguist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-translators.html) GUI.

Once the file is ready, you have to update [lang/languages.xml](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/blob/c3baf466c5ed088a9801c0ef2a07196ff30d053e/lang/languages.xml) file and create a relevant picture in PNG format in the flags folder.